# How to use custom twig functions in laravel using TwigBridge

Tags: php, twig, laravel

I'm using twig with laravel using [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge).  I'd like to register a custom function to use from within twig templates.

The documents states that extensions can be added via the extension-array, but this isn't clear to me.

What extension array is the documentation referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is referring is to [this array](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge/blob/master/src/config/extensions.php#L27) in the config file. You should publish the config to your **app/** using `php artisan config:publish rcrowe/twigbridge` and then edit that array. As you can see in the same config file you can also add alias.

You can create a class with your custom functions extending `\TwigBridge\Extension` and then add it to your config.

Answer (score 15):

**The process I followed was:**

1. Create my filters class at `app/extensions/twig/TwigFilters.php`:

   ```
   namespace App\Extensions\Twig;

   class TwigFilters extends \Twig_Extension {
       //... filters implementation
   }
   ```
2. Add the filter folder to composer.json `autoload > classmap`

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           ...
           "app/extensions/twig",
           ...
       ]
   },
   ```
3. Update autoloader: `php composer.phar dump-autoload`
4. Create the TwigBridge config at `app/config/packages/rcrowe/twigbridge/config.php`:

   ```
   php artisan config:publish rcrowe/twigbridge
   ```
5. Edit the `extensions` key on the previously created config.php:

   ```
   'extensions' => array(
       ...
       'App\Extensions\Twig\TwigFilters',
       ...
   )
   ```
6. All filters defined in that class are already available in the Twig views.

**Additional Info:**

- [Twig Extensions documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Great, but I also got mine to work without having to edit my `composer.json` file. It seems merely adding the extension to the `config/twigbridge.php` is enough.